# ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed (HOG)

Tags: python, histogram, gradient, scikit-image, histogram-of-oriented-gradients

I am implementing the HOG(Histogram of Oriented Gradient) with below code.

```
import io
from skimage.io import imread, imshow
from skimage.feature import hog
from skimage import exposure
from skimage import io
import matplotlib

img = imread('cr7.jpeg')

io.imshow(img)
MC = True #Fpr color images
#MC = false #for grayscale images

hogfv, hog_image = hog(img, orientations=9,
    pixels_per_cell=(32,32),
    cells_per_block=(4,4),
    visualize = True ,
    channel_axis=MC)
hog_image_rescaled = exposure.rescale_intensity(hog_image, in_range=(0,5))
imshow(hog_image_rescaled)
```

I don't know why i am getting error of dimension.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 22, in <module>
    channel_axis=MC)
  File "/Volumes/DATA/Djangoproject/HOG/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/skimage/_shared/utils.py", line 427, in fixed_func
    out = func(*new_args, **kwargs)
  File "/Volumes/DATA/Djangoproject/HOG/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/skimage/_shared/utils.py", line 348, in fixed_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Volumes/DATA/Djangoproject/HOG/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/skimage/feature/_hog.py", line 286, in hog
    dtype=float_dtype
ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed
(base) (env) c100-110@C100-110s-iMac-2 HOG % python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 18, in <module>
    channel_axis=MC)
  File "/Volumes/DATA/Djangoproject/HOG/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/skimage/_shared/utils.py", line 427, in fixed_func
    out = func(*new_args, **kwargs)
  File "/Volumes/DATA/Djangoproject/HOG/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/skimage/_shared/utils.py", line 348, in fixed_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Volumes/DATA/Djangoproject/HOG/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/skimage/feature/_hog.py", line 286, in hog
    dtype=float_dtype
ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed
```

Can anyone help me in finding solution to this error.

Comment: please edit the tags. this question is more about `scikit-image`, `histogram` and has nothing relevant to `matplotlib`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error log says there is a problem in "line 22"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 22, in <module>
    channel_axis=MC)
...
ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed
```

`channel_axis`, it's the "channel axis"! So I guess it expects an integer, rather than a bool value.

It is confirmed in the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/main/skimage/feature/_hog.py#L105):

> ```
> channel_axis : int or None, optional
> ```
>
> If None, the image is assumed to be a grayscale (single channel) image.
> Otherwise, this parameter indicates which axis of the array corresponds
> to channels.

I think you were trying to use `multichannel`, [which is deprecated](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/main/skimage/feature/_hog.py#L101):

> ```
> multichannel : boolean, optional
> ```
>
> If True, the last `image` dimension is considered as a color channel,
> otherwise as spatial. This argument is deprecated: specify `channel_axis` instead.

Comment: ```FutureWarning: `multichannel` is a deprecated argument name for `hog`. It will be removed in version 1.0. Please use `channel_axis` instead.
  multichannel=MC)``` It shows this error.

Comment: you should use `channel_axis` as in your original code and change the argument `MC` to `None` for gray image or a number that indicates which channel of the color image you are applying.

Answer (score 0):

By adding following, it is working for my case.

```
channel_axis=-1
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.